# Microsoft Access ODBC driver causes access violation when Access SQL functions are used

Tags: ms-access, odbc

I am using the Microsoft Access ODBC driver (installed by AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe) on my local machine to run "SQL" statements on an older Access database. Everything works fine here.

But now I am deploying it to a Docker container (using mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809-amd64) as the base image. My dockerfile installs .NET Core and also AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe. But when I run my app on the container, it executes hundreds of "SQL" statements just fine but then suddenly gets an AccessViolationException. I eventually figured out after running the same transaction script over and over that it was always crashing on the same query -- and the query contains IsNull().

I confirmed the driver files on the container match that of my local machine (both 64-bit only). For testing, I am using the exact same database on the local machine and container -- but that doesn't really matter because the database can be empty to get the access violation.

I've reduced the test application down to this simple program:

```
const string connectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=db\Test.mdb";
const string sql = "SELECT IsNull(null)";
var odbcConnection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
odbcConnection.Open();
odbcConnection.Execute(sql); // Dapper
```

On my local machine it works fine, but in the container this crashes with an AccessViolationException. Here is the exception right from the container output:

```
Fatal error. System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at Interop+Odbc.SQLExecDirectW(System.Data.Odbc.OdbcStatementHandle, System.String, Int32)
   at Interop+Odbc.SQLExecDirectW(System.Data.Odbc.OdbcStatementHandle, System.String, Int32)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcStatementHandle.ExecuteDirect(System.String)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(System.Data.CommandBehavior, System.String, Boolean, System.Object[], SQL_API)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(System.Data.CommandBehavior, System.String, Boolean)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteCommand(System.Data.IDbConnection, Dapper.CommandDefinition ByRef, System.Action`2<System.Data.IDbCommand,System.Object>)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteImpl(System.Data.IDbConnection, Dapper.CommandDefinition ByRef)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.Execute(System.Data.IDbConnection, System.String, System.Object, System.Data.IDbTransaction, System.Nullable`1<Int32>, System.Nullable`1<System.Data.CommandType>)
```

I want to clarify that I am running hundreds of other queries just fine on the container, but it always fails when IsNull() is anywhere in the command text.

So I was curious and tried some other Microsoft Access functions, like Now() and IsNumeric(1030). Those also throw AccessViolationException!

I am really struggling with how to continue to resolve this problem. Why is the driver behaving differently? Doesn't the driver support Microsoft Access functions, or is there a dependency I need to add to get full Microsoft Access support?

Thanks

Comment: IIRC Access requires .NET Framework, but ordinarily the installer should also install this for you. Try installing it next to .NET Core.

Comment: I installed, updated, and ngen'd .NET Framework 4.8 before installing .NET Core and unfortunately that didn't solve the problem. Also I tried installing accessruntime_4288-1001_x86_en-us.exe as described here ( https://www.itninja.com/software/microsoft/access-runtime/2016-1 ) and that didn't help either...

Comment: Ah, not a clue then, except that you can consider installing the full Access Runtime, since some of these functions are provided by the Access application and not the database engine. Do note that silent installs of the Access Database Engine skip several checks (such as checking for a conflicting Office install of a different bitness), I'd only switch to a silent install if you got everything working while manually installing.

Comment: Ah I just want to comment that I actually installed the x64 access runtime, sourced from here ( https://download.microsoft.com/download/D/B/D/DBD20EF9-A945-4768-AEB0-617BCEA2214A/accessruntime_4288-1001_x64_en-us.exe ). I mentioned in my previous comment, and I think you alluded to it, that I referenced x86. That was just a copy paste from the attached link. Also, a manual install is not an option here as it is going to a Docker container. However checking for Office conflicts (etc.) is not an issue as the target container is a fresh Windows install.

Comment: Yeah, I know in the end it needs to be a silent install, but for debugging purposes I recommend a manual install, since there might be more checks that get skipped during the silent one.

Comment: After looking at the Access Runtime log, I realized it failed. Error: 'CAInstallLicenses:  Populating the Token Store'; Installing license: sl.ISSUANCE.CLIENT_ROOT'; Error: Failed to open Token Store HResult: 0xc0020036. '; 'CustomAction CAInstallLicenses returned actual error code 1603  ... After searching i think it has to do with product activation. But since this is a Docker container I am not sure what is possible here. Nor am I completely confident this is the root cause of my main problem. Anybody have an idea how to get the Access Runtime to install on Docker?

Comment: See of this helps https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-access-accdb-odbc-driver/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I was getting the Access Violation is because I needed to install the Microsoft Access Runtime. Both the Access Database Engine and Microsoft Access Runtime are both required -- if only the database engine is installed connections to the MDB work but you cannot do anything fancy.

Now properly installing the Microsoft Access Runtime on a Docker container was no small feat. For that, there is a verbose answer to this question: [How to install Access Runtime on a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60380739/how-to-install-access-runtime-on-a-docker-container/60389706#60389706)

I want to add that I did not need any other dependencies to get this to work end-to-end. Not VC Runtime and not the .NET Framework.

Hope this helps somebody else in the future.