# How to install Access Runtime on a Docker container?

Tags: docker, ms-access, installation

I would like to install the Access Runtime on a Docker container, but I am getting a failure when doing so. Here are basic commands to reproduce the error.

First start an interactive shell with a new Windows container:

```
docker container run -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809-amd64 cmd.exe
```

Next run the following script to reproduce:

```
cd /d C:\
curl https://download.microsoft.com/download/D/B/D/DBD20EF9-A945-4768-AEB0-617BCEA2214A/accessruntime_4288-1001_x64_en-us.exe -o accessruntime_4288-1001_x64_en-us.exe
accessruntime_4288-1001_x64_en-us.exe /quiet /extract:C:\AccessRuntime
echo ^<Configuration Product="AccessRT"^> > accessruntime_4288-1001_x64_en-us.config
echo ^<Display Level="None" CompletionNotice="no" SuppressModal="yes" AcceptEula="yes" /^> >> accessruntime_4288-1001_x64_en-us.config
echo ^<Logging Type="standard" Path="C:\Windows\Temp\" Template="Microsoft_Access_2016_Runtime_Setup(*).log" /^> >> accessruntime_4288-1001_x64_en-us.config
echo ^<COMPANYNAME Value="Company Name" /^> >> accessruntime_4288-1001_x64_en-us.config
echo ^<Setting Id="SETUP_REBOOT" Value="Never" /^> >> accessruntime_4288-1001_x64_en-us.config
echo ^</Configuration^> >> accessruntime_4288-1001_x64_en-us.config
del C:\Windows\Temp\Microsoft_Access_2016_Runtime_Setup*.log
cmd /C C:\AccessRuntime\setup.exe /config C:\accessruntime_4288-1001_x64_en-us.config
echo Access Runtime Setup exited with code: %errorlevel%, See below for logs:
findstr /spin CAInstallLicenses C:\Windows\Temp\Microsoft_Access_2016_Runtime_Setup*.log
```

For readability, this is the config the script generates as an input:

```
<Configuration Product="AccessRT">
<Display Level="None" CompletionNotice="no" SuppressModal="yes" AcceptEula="yes" />
<Logging Type="standard" Path="C:\Windows\Temp\" Template="Microsoft_Access_2016_Runtime_Setup(*).log" />
<COMPANYNAME Value="Company Name" />
<Setting Id="SETUP_REBOOT" Value="Never" />
</Configuration>
```

Here is the output:

```
Access Runtime Setup exited with code: 1603, See below for logs:

C:\Windows\Temp\Microsoft_Access_2016_Runtime_Setup(2020022408475199C).log:9975:2020/02/24 08:49:01:598::[1176] MSI(ACTIONSTART): 'Action 8:49:01: PrepareCAInstallLicenses. '
C:\Windows\Temp\Microsoft_Access_2016_Runtime_Setup(2020022408475199C).log:9976:2020/02/24 08:49:01:598::[1176] MSI(INFO): 'Action start 8:49:01: PrepareCAInstallLicenses.'
C:\Windows\Temp\Microsoft_Access_2016_Runtime_Setup(2020022408475199C).log:9977:2020/02/24 08:49:01:614::[1176] MSI(INFO): 'PrepareCAInstallLicenses:  OMSICA : Initializing CustomAction PrepareCAInstallLicens
es'
C:\Windows\Temp\Microsoft_Access_2016_Runtime_Setup(2020022408475199C).log:9978:2020/02/24 08:49:01:630::[1176] MSI(INFO): 'PrepareCAInstallLicenses:  PHN license not supplied for ACID: 9D9FAF9E-D345-4B49-AFC
E-68CB0A539C7C'
C:\Windows\Temp\Microsoft_Access_2016_Runtime_Setup(2020022408475199C).log:9979:2020/02/24 08:49:01:630::[1176] MSI(INFO): 'PrepareCAInstallLicenses:  RAC-Private license not supplied for ACID: 9D9FAF9E-D345-
4B49-AFCE-68CB0A539C7C'
C:\Windows\Temp\Microsoft_Access_2016_Runtime_Setup(2020022408475199C).log:9980:2020/02/24 08:49:01:630::[1176] MSI(INFO): 'PrepareCAInstallLicenses:  RAC-Public license not supplied for ACID: 9D9FAF9E-D345-4
B49-AFCE-68CB0A539C7C'
C:\Windows\Temp\Microsoft_Access_2016_Runtime_Setup(2020022408475199C).log:9981:2020/02/24 08:49:01:645::[1176] MSI(INFO): 'Action ended 8:49:01: PrepareCAInstallLicenses. Return value 1.'
C:\Windows\Temp\Microsoft_Access_2016_Runtime_Setup(2020022408475199C).log:10205:2020/02/24 08:49:09:708::[1176] MSI(ACTIONSTART): 'Action 8:49:09: CAInstallLicenses. '
C:\Windows\Temp\Microsoft_Access_2016_Runtime_Setup(2020022408475199C).log:10206:2020/02/24 08:49:09:708::[1176] MSI(INFO): 'Action start 8:49:09: CAInstallLicenses.'
C:\Windows\Temp\Microsoft_Access_2016_Runtime_Setup(2020022408475199C).log:10207:2020/02/24 08:49:09:723::[1176] MSI(INFO): 'Action ended 8:49:09: CAInstallLicenses. Return value 1.'
C:\Windows\Temp\Microsoft_Access_2016_Runtime_Setup(2020022408475199C).log:10275:2020/02/24 08:49:32:270::[1176] MSI(ACTIONSTART): 'Action 8:49:32: CAInstallLicenses. '
C:\Windows\Temp\Microsoft_Access_2016_Runtime_Setup(2020022408475199C).log:10276:2020/02/24 08:49:32:286::[1176] MSI(INFO): 'CAInstallLicenses:  OMSICA : Initializing CustomAction CAInstallLicenses'
C:\Windows\Temp\Microsoft_Access_2016_Runtime_Setup(2020022408475199C).log:10277:2020/02/24 08:49:32:302::[1176] MSI(INFO): 'CAInstallLicenses:  Populating the Token Store'
C:\Windows\Temp\Microsoft_Access_2016_Runtime_Setup(2020022408475199C).log:10278:2020/02/24 08:49:32:302::[1176] MSI(INFO): 'CAInstallLicenses:  Installing license: sl.ISSUANCE.CLIENT_ROOT'
C:\Windows\Temp\Microsoft_Access_2016_Runtime_Setup(2020022408475199C).log:10279:2020/02/24 08:49:32:302::[1176] MSI(INFO): 'CAInstallLicenses:  Error: Failed to open Token Store HResult: 0xc0020036. '
C:\Windows\Temp\Microsoft_Access_2016_Runtime_Setup(2020022408475199C).log:10280:2020/02/24 08:49:32:302::[1176] MSI(INFO): 'CustomAction CAInstallLicenses returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not b
e 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)'
C:\Windows\Temp\Microsoft_Access_2016_Runtime_Setup(2020022408475199C).log:11247:2020/02/24 08:50:08:161::[1176] MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): CAInstallLicenses = **********'
C:\Windows\Temp\Microsoft_Access_2016_Runtime_Setup(2020022408475199C).log:11405:2020/02/24 08:50:08:208::[1176] MSI(INFO): 'Property(S): MsiHiddenProperties = CAInstallLicenses;CAInstallPidKey;DigitalProduct
ID;DPID;PIDKEY;VerifyProdReg'
```

Searching for this error makes me believe it has something to do with Windows or Office activation. But since this is a Docker container, how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After many many hours of trial and error and internet searching, I can happily say that I managed to get the Access Runtime successfully installed on a Docker container. A response on [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/problem-activation-error-0xc0020036-windows-10/85126b3c-8476-4310-83bf-4d9c7801d39b) led me in the right direction.

The sun, moon, and stars must all align to get this to work, so I hope this answer helps somebody out in the future.

First, for the record, I am using base image **FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809-amd64**, which is deployable to Azure. Unfortunately a servercore image isn't an option because the Access Database Engine (a separate dependency I had) doesn't work on servercore.

Second, during the install you must be using **USER ContainerAdministrator**.

Third, before running setup.exe you must set this registry key:

```
reg.exe add HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\sppsvc /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
```

I don't entirely know what this does, but has does something to do with activation. It puts the OS in a state which is sufficient enough for the Access Runtime to be installed. This the piece I got on that thread.

By default the value was 4, and this puts the value to 2. After the install I did not restore this to 4, nor did I test it.

Another important point is that setting this registry setting must be in a **RUN** statement before and independently of the **RUN** which launches setup.exe. This is because a reboot is required after setting it. This means one cannot manually test this alone from a shell, and must use a Dockerfile to test this end-to-end.

Fourth, when launching setup.exe you must launch it in a very specific way:

```
RUN cmd.exe /C setup.exe /config temp.log
```

What is important here is the extra cmd.exe /C. The reason for that is because setup.exe launches a new shell and returns immediately if you don't have cmd.exe /C. This means the action yields immediately back to Docker and it gets into a wierd state. It took me a while to figure that out. cmd.exe /C allows it to sufficiently wait. In fact I use PowerShell just to be extra certain:

```
$access_runtime_setup_process = Start-Process -FilePath 'cmd.exe' -ArgumentList \"/C $access_runtime_temp_directory\setup.exe /config $access_runtime_config_file\" -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru; `
if ($access_runtime_setup_process.ExitCode -ne 0) { `
    Write-Host \"PROCESS FAILED: $access_runtime_temp_directory\setup.exe (Exit Code: $($access_runtime_setup_process.ExitCode))\"; `
    exit 1; `
}
```

Finally, I ended up installing the Access Database Engine after the Access Runtime. I didn't test the other way around, it probably works also.

After installing the Access Database Engine, I did a **USER ContainerUser** to restore the user.

I did not need the VC Runtime or the .NET Framework installed, the only things I needed to install were the runtime and database engine.

If anybody else ends up having to experience the pain of using legacy software like Access in a Docker container, I hope this helps you!

Comment: Great stuff, but why do you say Microsoft Access is "legacy software"?

Comment: Can you share the full dockerfile?

Answer (score 2):

I really struggled to get the access database engine running in a container for ci builds. My .NET app uses `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` data provider to import data from excel files and I wanted my test to run inside a docker container

I am using `mcr.microsoft.com/windows:ltsc2019` container image and this post here was the best source to get started.

However, I tried everything from @Agendum 's solution and much more but I couldn't manage to sucessfully install the runtime.

Eventually I found a solution myself which I want to share

First I downloaded the `Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable` from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

The direct links are https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/5/C/35C84C36-661A-44E6-9324-8786B8DBE231/accessdatabaseengine.exe and https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/5/C/35C84C36-661A-44E6-9324-8786B8DBE231/accessdatabaseengine_X64.exe

After that I installed the runtime with

```
cmd.exe /c accessdatabaseengine.exe /quiet /norestart
```

I found the switch documented [here](https://silentinstallhq.com/microsoft-access-database-engine-2016-redistributable-silent-install-how-to-guide/)

As @Agendum mentioned, without the `cmd.exe /c` the command would return immediately and the setup would continue in the background. The neat thing is that you can install both runtimes in parallel, which I believe wouldn't be possible without the `/quiet` switch because if one version is installed the setup would refuse to install the other.

Here is a fully working dockerfile.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:ltsc2019

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command"]

WORKDIR C:\\Tools

# install Access Database Engine
RUN curl https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/5/C/35C84C36-661A-44E6-9324-8786B8DBE231/accessdatabaseengine.exe -o accessdatabaseengine.exe; \
    cmd.exe /c accessdatabaseengine.exe /quiet /norestart; \
    curl https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/5/C/35C84C36-661A-44E6-9324-8786B8DBE231/accessdatabaseengine_X64.exe -o accessdatabaseengine_X64.exe; \
    cmd.exe /c accessdatabaseengine_x64.exe /quiet /norestart; \
    del accessdatabaseengine*.exe
```

Comment: `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:ltsc2019` leads to an error, is there anything else I could use?

Comment: I installed windows feature "containers" on a server 2019. You can either switch to hyper-v isolation or use another base image. ltsc2022 might work, too. See the compatibility matrix here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility?tabs=windows-server-2022%2Cwindows-11

Comment: Ah yes, with with windows containers it worked now! Thanks a lot! But I really don't like this base image. It's huge. But I guess I will have to work with it now, the others didn't work.

Comment: Yes, its huge. But I needed it for a couple of other features as well. Running unit test that print out a pdf file need a spooler which is also not available in server core. You can either have only one running container using the spooler but have to disable the service on the host or use hyperv isolation but hyperv isolation has an interesting kernel with an utf codepage https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40535#issuecomment-930650879

Comment: For some reason, using the 2016 version from a .NET Framework app crashes the app instantly without even being able to catch the exception (neither with the `[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]` attribute). Using 2010 redistributable works fine.